# The Query is not working when I am adding a CTE command to it , although the Inside Select Query is giving the coorect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

In **First Image** Only Select Statement is run , it works fine .

but In **Second Image** when we *added CTE and executed the query , it shows error.*

Can you please help me with this ???

Comment: Show us sample table data, the expected result, and your current query attempt - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) [mcve]

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? tag spamming does not help.

Comment: I have remove the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: You define your cte but never actually select from it. When you create a cte it is like an inline view. Why do you need a cte for this? Also do yourself a favor and don't be scared to format your queries so you can read them.

Answer (score 0):

It says `Incorrect syntax near ';'` because you have a `WITH` statement ended with a `;` and no further `SELECT` after it.

The query itself is fine, that's why it works up top. But when using `WITH`, you have to follow it up with more querying.

Delete the exiting `;` and ddd `SELECT * FROM cte1;` after it.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE generate a image of a table, so you need to make a `select` afterwards as well.

`with cte1 (...) select * from cte1;`